# How to include local headers without writing full path

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, preprocessor

- 

My project looks like

```
project
│
├── bin
│    └── makefile
├── include
│      ├── defs.h
│      ├── func.h
│      └── print.h
└── src
     ├── func.c
     ├── main.c
     └── print.c
```

and makefile is

```
OBJS = func.o print.o main.o
TARGET = program

INCLUDE_DIR = ../include
SRC_DIR = ../src

vpath %.h $(INCLUDE_DIR)
vpath %.c $(SRC_DIR)

.PHONY: clean

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

$(OBJS): defs.h

clean:
    rm $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

but when i type "make" i get this

```
cc    -c -o func.o ../src/func.c
cc    -c -o print.o ../src/print.c
cc    -c -o main.o ../src/main.c
../src/main.c:1:10: fatal error: func.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
 #include "func.h"
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<встроенное>: main.o] Ошибка 1
```

(Sorry for russian text, it's something like there is no such file or directory)

I know that I can write #include "../include/func.c" but is there other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this, now my makefile looks like this:

```
OBJS = func.o print.o main.o
TARGET = program

INCLUDE_DIR = ../include
SRC_DIR = ../src

vpath %.h $(INCLUDE_DIR)
vpath %.c $(SRC_DIR)

.PHONY: clean

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

main.o: main.c defs.h
    $(CC) -c -o $@ -I$(INCLUDE_DIR) $<

$(OBJS): defs.h

clean:
    rm $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```